# C# Async Socket Client Blocks Main Interface Thread

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asynchronous, timeout

Another networking question this time related to an Async Socket Client which is based on the MSDN examples at least for this initial version.  Currently when the user clicks a button on the interface an Async Connect attempt is made to connect to a networked device, the code is shown below -

```
//Mouse Event handler for main thread
private void btn_Read_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    if (!networkDev.Connected)
        networkDev.Connect("192.168.1.176", 1025);

    if(networkDev.Connected)
       networkDev.getReading();
    sw.Stop();//Time time taken...
}
```

If the end point is switched on and exists on the network this code works fine (less than a second for whole operation).  However should the networked device be switched off or unavailable the AsyncSocket Connect function holds up the main forms thread.  Currently if the device is unavailable the whole interface locks up for about 20 seconds (using the stopwatch).  I think that I am locking because the main thread is waiting for the return on the Connect request, does this mean I need to put that connect request on another thread?

I have included the code the Async Socket Client I am using -

```
    public bool Connect(String ip_address, UInt16 port)
    {
        bool success = false;

        try
        {
            IPAddress ip;
            success = IPAddress.TryParse(ip_address, out ip);
            if (success)
                success = Connect(ip, port);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return success;
    }     

    public bool Connect(IPAddress ip_address, UInt16 port)
    {
        mSocket.BeginConnect(ip_address, port, 
           new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), mSocket);
        connectDone.WaitOne();//Blocks until the connect operation completes, 
                              //(time taken?) timeout?
        return mSocket.Connected;
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //Retreive the socket from thestate object
        try
        {
            Socket mSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            //Set signal for Connect done so that thread will come out of 
            //WaitOne state and continue
            connectDone.Set();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }       
    }
```

I was hoping that by using an Async client which has its own thread that this would then stop freezing the interface if the host didn't exist but this does not appear to be the case.  After the initial connect failure which takes 20s all subsequent connection attempts are returned immediately (less than a ms).  Also something I thought strange, if the initial connection attempt succeeds, any later calls to connect to a non existent host return immediately.  A little baffled by what is happening but wondering if its related to the fact that the Socket I use is stored in my AsyncSocket class.  Any help much appreciated, if more of the client code is required let me know.

Comment: You see where in the comment next to WaitOne it says "blocks until operation completes"? How exactly is that asynchronous and which thread do you think it blocks.

Comment: I have taken this out now as this is with hindsight, blindingly obvious the problem with the freezing interface.  This solves the interface problem which was the initial question, though it seems if the Connect is unable to complete I cannot use that socket again, and this is a problem when disconnects may happen relatively frequently.  Each AsyncClient is tied to 1 Socket, whats the best way to allow a reconnect?  Currently I just get exceptions saying that the thread is waiting for the previous begin connect.  Any suggestions on a better solution are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You claim it's asynchronous, but your Connect method clearly isn't:

```
mSocket.BeginConnect(ip_address, port, ...);
connectDone.WaitOne(); // Blocks until the connect operation completes [...]
```

You're blocking until it's completed, which is the antithesis of asynchronous behaviour. What's the point of using `BeginConnect` if you're going to block until it's connected?

Comment: Hmm I used the MSDN example to base my code on so I cannot understand why they put a WaitOne into the connect?  I was hoping the example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx) would have been a decent one and good starting point.  Seems I was wrong!  Without the wait one if I press the button a few times it puts up many exceptions stating cannot connect while another operation is in progress.  Is there anyway to timeout the other connection attempts faster so that in an unstable environment the reconnect attempts can be made more often?

Comment: @jackocurly0074: I can't *see* any connection timeout properties, no... but you should probably ensure that you *don't* try to make multiple concurrent connections.

Answer (score 1):

You're blocking your UI thread here:

```
connectDone.WaitOne();  //Blocks until the connect operation completes, (time taken?) timeout?
```

Comment: You guys are very fast at replying, thanks!  Taking out the WaitOne stops the interface from freezing but creates another problem.  This happens on subsequent connect attempts ->

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
BeginConnect cannot be called while another asynchronous operation is in progress on the same Socket.
The problem is that once the socket fails to connect I cannot use it again and it appears to be unusuable for the rest of the runtime in question?